# Não consigo chamar função JavaScript no textBox

Tags: javascript, c#, textbox

Tenho a seguinte função java script para formatar meus campos de data:

```
function MascaraData(data){
if(mascaraInteiro(data)==false){
    event.returnValue = false;
    }   
return formataCampo(data, '00/00/0000', event);
}
```

porém não consigo chamar a função no textBox da minha página

[image: meu campo TextBox data inicio]

Comment: Se possível, inclua na pergunta também as mensagens do Console do seu browser :)

Comment: Já considerou usar o jQuery.mask() ?

Comment: $("#TextBoxDataInicio").mask("99/99/9999");

Comment: Com asp ou input?

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi da seguinte maneira:

```
onKeyUp="MascaraData(this)"
```

Answer (score 0):

tenta assim.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="MascaraData();" id="TextBoxDataInicio" />



function MascaraData() {

    TextBoxDataInicio = document.getElementById("TextBoxDataInicio");
    data = TextBoxDataInicio.value;

    if (mascaraInteiro(data) == false) {
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
    TextBoxDataInicio.value = formataCampo(data, '00/00/0000', event);
}
```

Comment: se eu mudar para input, vai comprometer umas coisas que tenho aqui no projeto. Tem que ser asp: mesmo.

Comment: O input foi o que usei para teste, para mostrar que não precisaria passar "form1.data". Você pode continuar usando o asp:TextBox